# Notepad++ regex add lines, copy string

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to search replace & strings in thousands of wavefront *.mtl files to add many new Texture links. Is this even possible with Notepad++ regex? I´ve already altered these files very often with regex, but this task is way over my head!

At the current state I got many Materialparts in every file looking like this:

```
newmtl Material__28
    Ns 0.000000
         ︙
    Kd 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
    Ks 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
    Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000

    map_Kd textures\wall_exterior_wood_02.png
```

where the dots represent text that I don't want to change
(and that doesn't contain the string `map_Kd`).

And afterwards it should contain the NRM & Spec PNGs named exactly like the first `map_Kd`.

Example:

```
newmtl Material__28
    Ns 0.000000
         ︙
    Kd 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
    Ks 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
    Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000

    map_Kd   textures\wall_exterior_wood_02.png
    map_bump textures\wall_exterior_wood_02_nrm.png
    map_bump textures\wall_exterior_wood_02_nrm alternative.png
    map_Ks   textures\wall_exterior_wood_02_spec.png
```

I've added spaces to the `map` lines for clarity.
Important is that the naming of the PNGs should be the same except for the prefixes "`map_bump`" and "`map_ks`" and the postfixes "`_nrm`", "`_nrm alternative`", and "`_spec`".

Answer (score 4):

In Notepad++.

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> (replace)

Select "Regular Expression" radio button in the Search Mode box in the bottom left
(making sure the matches newline tickbox is unticked)

Find:

`map_Kd\s+(\S+)\.png`

Replace:

`map_Kd   \1.png\n    map_bump \1_nrm.png\n    map_bump \1_nrm_alternative.png\n    mapKs    \1_spec.png`

The find expression looks for "map_Kd" followed by one or more spaces ("`\s+`") then keeps one or more non-space characters ("`(\S+)`") until it hits "`.png`"

The replace puts the string you kept in wherever "`\1`" appears. I've also included "`\n`" newlines and spacing to align things as in your example.

Comment: You sir are my Notepad++ hero!